# SVN export throws "project/subfolder/ is not a working copy" for non-existing "subfolder"

Tags: svn

I am trying to export the working copy of an SVN project to some other folder. When I do svn export I get :

```
'D:\project\trunk\subfolder' is not a working copy.
```

I read that this might happen when **subfolder** does not have a .svn directory (so it is not being tracked by SVN). However in this case the **subfolder** directory does not exist. I imagine it is being tracked in some SVN metadata where I must remove the reference, but do not know where to look for it.

Anyone knows how to fix this so that I can do the clean svn export?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: I found the solution to this problem the following way:

1. Run a  `grep -R subfolder *` in the project folder
2. This showed me one .svn/entries file were the aforementioned folder 'subfolder' was present in the form:

> add
>
> FF
>   subfolder
>
> dir

I removed the references to such folder in the file and then could to a clean svn export without problems.

Before that I tried doing an `svn update` but that did not change anything. I *think* the problem was that the folder was added to the project and then deleted without telling svn.